# How to transfer data from an HTML form to a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a form which accepts values from the user and then passes those values to a JS function in the same file for some calculations. I'm just trying to print the values to the console right now, but I keep getting the error `"Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementByID'"`. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="javascript:formHandler();" method="get">
    <h1 align="center">Set the parameters you would like to visualize</h1>

    Center Frequency: <input type="text" name="cf" id="cf"><br>
    Bandwidth: <input type="text" name="bw" id="bw"><br>
    Number of Bins: <input type="text" name="bins" id="bins"><br>
    Number of Values to be Visualized: <input type="text" name="values" id="values"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>


    function formHandler()
    {
            console.log(document.getElementByID("cf")); // This is where I'm getting the error
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does it mean **transfer data from an HTML form to a JavaScript function** ?

Comment: I'm trying to send the center frequency, bandwidth, bins, and values to the JavaScript function. I want to log the center frequency to the console for now. Sorry for the bad phrasing.

Comment: I think, you are trying to retrieve textbox value when function called, is it ?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `document.getElementByID` should have a **lowercase** d at the end and you should also add .value, like so

`document.getElementById("id").value`

to get the value of whats being pass or typed

Comment: I tried what you suggested in combination with what jWeaver suggested, and it works, but the value only appears in the console for a split-second. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: your form is submitting so the page is being reload. in your form add this action="javascript:formHandler(); return false;"

Comment: What if I wanted to store the value in a variable and not have the value disappear once the page reloads?

Comment: once the page reloads everything resets, that includes variables. if you wanna save the values that are passed or type i suggest using a database or passing them to global variables like POST or GET then grabbing it again when the page loads

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo error. It should be `getElementById` and not `getElementByID`.

You can print the value to console as below:

`console.log(document.getElementById("cf").value);`

Answer (score 1):

Better if you do like this

```
<form action='somepage.html' OnSubmit="return formHandler();" method="get">
<h1 align="center">Set the parameters you would like to visualize</h1>

Center Frequency: <input type="text" name="cf" id="cf"><br>
Bandwidth: <input type="text" name="bw" id="bw"><br>
Number of Bins: <input type="text" name="bins" id="bins"><br>
Number of Values to be Visualized: <input type="text" name="values" id="values"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<script type='text/javascript'>
function formHandler()
{
        console.log(document.getElementById("cf").value);
  return true;
}
</script>
```